# How to assign a Site Administration role for a user in liferay programatically?

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am creating the user programatically by calling the `UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(....)` and able to assign the site for the created user by calling `UserLocalServiceUtil.addRoleUser(userSiteId, userId)` It is working fine. I am able to assign the site membership for the user. But how can I assign the Site Administration permission for creates user. (So for I am able to assign user as site member but I need to assign user as a site administrator)

Any suggestions please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil to assign "Site Administration" role under the Site roles.

```
Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, "Site Administrator");
long[] SiteroleIds = {role.getRoleId()};
UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserGroupRoles(userId, siteId, SiteroleIds);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use RoleLocalServiceUtil to get object of any role.

```
Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(roleId);
UserLocalServiceUtil.addRoleUser(role.getRoleId(), user.getUserId());
UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(user);
```

Comment: If I user "RoleLocalServiceUtil" to define a role for user as you suggested will the user get site admin role permissions OR site member role permissions?

Comment: Yes, just pass pk of specific role as roleId.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. how can I pass pk for that roleId.

Comment: you will find role id for specific role from Role_ table.

Comment: I did as you suggested. But "Site Administration" role is assigned in the Regular role. Not in the Site role. How can i assign it as a Site Role? thanks in advance